# How to select Y values at X position in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, graph, interpolation, cross-correlation

this is sort of a mathy question...

I had a question prior to this about normalizing monthly data here : 
[How to produce X values of a stretched graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588535/how-to-produce-x-values-of-a-stretched-graph)

I got a good answer and it works well, the only issue is that now I need to check X values of one month with 31 days against X values of a month with 28.

So my question would be: If I have two sets of parameters like so:

```
x    |    y           x2    |     y2

1    |    10        1.0    |     10
2    |    9         1.81    |     9.2
3    |    8         2.63    |     8.6
4    |    7         3.45    |     7.8
5    |    6         4.27    |     7
6    |    5         5.09    |     6.2
7    |    4         5.91    |     5.4
8    |    3         6.73    |     4.2
9    |    2         7.55    |     3.4
10   |    1         8.36    |     2.6
                    9.18    |     1.8
                    10.0    |     1.0
```

As you can see, the general trend is the same for these two data sets.
However, if I run these values through a cross-correlation function (the general goal), I will get something back that does not reflect this, since the data sets are of two different sizes.

The real world example of this would be, say, if you are tracking how many miles you run per day:

In February (with 28 days), during the first week, you run one mile each day. During the second week, you run two miles each day, etc.

In March (with 31 days), you do the same thing, but run for one mile for eight days, two miles for eight days, three miles for eight days, and four miles for seven days.

The correlation coefficient according to the following function should be almost exactly 1:

```
class CrossCorrelator {

    def variance = { x->
        def v = 0
        x.each{ v += it**2}
        v/(x.size()) - (mean(x)**2)
    }

    def covariance = {x, y->
        def z = 0
        [x, y].transpose().each{ z += it[0] * it[1] }
        (z / (x.size())) - (mean(x) * mean(y))
    }
    def coefficient = {x, y->
        covariance(x,y) / (Math.sqrt(variance(x) * variance(y)))
    }
}
def i = new CrossCorrelator()
i.coefficient(y values, y2 values)
```

Just looking at the data sets, it seems like the graphs would be exactly the same if I were to grab the values at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10, and the function would produce a more accurate result.

However, it's skewed since the lengths are not the same.

Is there some way to locate what the values at the integers in the twelve-value data set would be? I haven't found a simple way to do it, but this would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks in advance,

5

Edit: As per request, here is the code that generates the X values of the graphs:

```
def x  = (1..12) 
def y = 10

change = {l, size ->
    v = [1]
    l.each{
        v << ((((size-1)/(x.size() - 1)) * it) + 1)
    }
    v -= v.last()
    return v
}


change(x, y)
```

Edit: Not working code as per another request:

```
def normalize( xylist, days ) {
  xylist.collect { x, y -> [ x * ( days / xylist.size() ), y ] }
}

def change = {l, size ->
    def v = [1]
    l.each{
        v << ((((size-1)/(l.size() - 1)) * it) + 1)
    }
    v -= v.last()
    return v
}

def resample( list, min, max ) {
   // We want a graph with integer points from min to max on the x axis
  (min..max).collect { i ->
    // find the values above and below this point
    bounds = list.inject( [ a:null, b:null ] ) { r, p ->
      // if the value is less than i, set it in r.a
      if( p[ 0 ] < i )
        r.a = p
      // if it's bigger (and we don't already have a bigger point)
      // then set it into r.b
      if( !r.b && p[ 0 ] >= i )
        r.b = p
      r
    }
    // so now, bounds.a is the point below our required point, and bounds.b
    // Deal with the first case (where a is null, because we are at the start)
    if( !bounds.a )
      [ i, list[ 0 ][ 1 ] ]
    else {
      // so work out the distance from bounds.a to bounds.b
      dist = ( bounds.b[0] - bounds.a[0] )
      // And how far the point i is along this line
      r = ( i - bounds.a[0] ) / dist
      // and recalculate the y figure for this point
      y = ( ( bounds.b[1] - bounds.a[1] ) * r ) + bounds.a[1]
      [ i, y ]
    }
  }
}

def feb = [9, 3, 7, 23, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 14, 8, 13, 12, 15, 6, 7, 13, 19, 12, 7, 3, 4, 15, 6, 17, 8, 19]
def march = [8, 12, 4, 17, 11, 15, 12, 8, 9, 13, 12, 7, 3, 4, 8, 2, 17, 19, 21, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 7, 8, 19, 21, 14, 16]

//X and Y Values for February
z = [(1..28), change(feb, 28)].transpose()

//X and Y Values for March stretched to 28 entries
o = [(1..31), change(march, 28)].transpose()

o1 = normalize(o, 28)

resample(o1, 1, 28)
```

If I switch "march" in the o variable declaration to (1..31), the script runs successfully. When I try to use "march," I get "
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object"

Also: I try not to directly copy code just because it's bad practice, so one of the functions I changed basically does the same thing, it's just my version. I'll get around to refactoring the rest of it eventually, too. But that's why it's slightly different.

Comment: Well, these were just some values produced by me to fake some data. I will revise the original post with the way that I got the X values, though. The Y values are made up, but the y values are basically just the x values in reverse order. That's what they should be. Anyway, the post will be updated with the X-getting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok...here we go...this may not be the cleanest bit of code ever...

Let's first generate two distributions, both from 1 to 10 (in the y axis)

```
def generate( range, max ) {
  range.collect { i ->
    [ i, max * ( i / ( range.to - range.from + 1 ) ) ]
  }
}

// A distribution 10 elements long from 1 to 10
def e1 = generate( 1..10, 10 )
// A distribution 14 elements long from 1 to 10
def e2 = generate( 1..14, 10 )
```

So now, e1 and e2 are:

```
[1.00,1.00], [2.00,2.00], [3.00,3.00], [4.00,4.00], [5.00,5.00], [6.00,6.00], [7.00,7.00], [8.00,8.00], [9.00,9.00], [10.00,10.00]
[1.00,0.71], [2.00,1.43], [3.00,2.14], [4.00,2.86], [5.00,3.57], [6.00,4.29], [7.00,5.00], [8.00,5.71], [9.00,6.43], [10.00,7.14], [11.00,7.86], [12.00,8.57], [13.00,9.29], [14.00,10.00]
```

respectively (to 2dp).  Now, using the code from the previous question, we can normalize these to the same x range:

```
def normalize( xylist, days ) {
  xylist.collect { x, y -> [ x * ( days / xylist.size() ), y ] }
}

n1 = normalize( e1, 10 )
n2 = normalize( e2, 10 )
```

This means n1 and n2 are:

```
[1.00,1.00], [2.00,2.00], [3.00,3.00], [4.00,4.00], [5.00,5.00], [6.00,6.00], [7.00,7.00], [8.00,8.00], [9.00,9.00], [10.00,10.00]
[0.71,0.71], [1.43,1.43], [2.14,2.14], [2.86,2.86], [3.57,3.57], [4.29,4.29], [5.00,5.00], [5.71,5.71], [6.43,6.43], [7.14,7.14], [7.86,7.86], [8.57,8.57], [9.29,9.29], [10.00,10.00]
```

But, as you correctly state they have different numbers of sample points, so cannot be compared easily.

But we can write a method to step through each point we **want** in our graph, fond the two closest points, and interpolate a y value from the values of these two points like so:

```
def resample( list, min, max ) {
   // We want a graph with integer points from min to max on the x axis
  (min..max).collect { i ->
    // find the values above and below this point
    bounds = list.inject( [ a:null, b:null ] ) { r, p ->
      // if the value is less than i, set it in r.a
      if( p[ 0 ] < i )
        r.a = p
      // if it's bigger (and we don't already have a bigger point)
      // then set it into r.b
      if( !r.b && p[ 0 ] >= i )
        r.b = p
      r
    }
    // so now, bounds.a is the point below our required point, and bounds.b
    if( !bounds.a )             // no lower bound...take the first element
      [ i, list[ 0 ][ 1 ] ]
    else if( !bounds.b )        // no upper bound... take the last element
      [ i, list[ -1 ][ 1 ] ]
    else {
      // so work out the distance from bounds.a to bounds.b
      dist = ( bounds.b[0] - bounds.a[0] )
      // And how far the point i is along this line
      r = ( i - bounds.a[0] ) / dist
      // and recalculate the y figure for this point
      y = ( ( bounds.b[1] - bounds.a[1] ) * r ) + bounds.a[1]
      [ i, y ]
    }
  }
}    
final1 = resample( n1, 1, 10 )
final2 = resample( n2, 1, 10 )
```

now, the values `final1` and `final2` are:

```
[1.00,1.00], [2.00,2.00], [3.00,3.00], [4.00,4.00], [5.00,5.00], [6.00,6.00], [7.00,7.00], [8.00,8.00], [9.00,9.00], [10.00,10.00]
[1.00,1.00], [2.00,2.00], [3.00,3.00], [4.00,4.00], [5.00,5.00], [6.00,6.00], [7.00,7.00], [8.00,8.00], [9.00,9.00], [10.00,10.00]
```

(obviously, there is some rounding here, so 2d.p. is hiding the fact that they are not **exactly** the same)

Phew...  Must be home-time after that ;-)

### EDIT

As pointed out in the edit to the question, there was a bug in my `resample` method that caused it to fail in certain conditions...

I believe this has now been fixed in the code above, and from the given example:

```
def march = [8, 12, 4, 17, 11, 15, 12, 8, 9, 13, 12, 7, 3, 4, 8, 2, 17, 19, 21, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 7, 8, 19, 21, 14, 16]
o = [ (1..31), march ].transpose()

// X values squeezed to be between 1 and 28 (instead of 1 to 31)
o1 = normalize(o, 28)

// Then, resample this graph so there are only 28 points
v = resample(o1, 1, 28)
```

If you plot the original 31 points (in `o`) and the new graph of 28 points (in `v`), you get:

[image]

Which doesn't look too bad.

I have no idea what the `change` method was supposed to do, so I have omitted it from this code

Comment: You, sir, are one of the most helpful people ever. This is exactly what I wanted to do, including the interpolation bit (finding the points between two existing points)... the thought of it just made my brain hurt and I'm not efficient enough in Groovy yet to figure out the structure of this problem in my head. Brilliant. Thank you, once again!

Comment: Hope it all makes sense :-) it gets a bit rough round the inject block, but that was the first function that came to mind when trying to get the local min and max points. There is probably something more optimal that can replace that...

Comment: I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to use a fairly random set of Y values. Is this because there are multiples of the same number? Will the bounds necessarily correspond to the graph, or will say, the number "2.34" use any "2" as a lower and any "3" as an upper bound? If I have a list of Y values that are, say [1, 3, 7, 1], will trying to find the value at 1.5 result in an error due to trying to locate the value between 1 and 3 AND 1 and 7?

Comment: Can you post a simple failing example at the end of your question, and I'll have a look :-)

Comment: quick question...  what does `change` do?

Comment: updated the `resample` method...  And plotted an output comparing the before and after plots... fingers crossed ;-)  -- obviously, some data is lost through [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)

Comment: Looks good! The "change" method was another way of normalizing the data...the way I was using it, there was no point to having it so it was fine to omit. I will work with this, thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck again! :-)